# How to wait for an event in AppDelegate to be completed (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Coming from C#/Java/JS, I'm just starting to learn Swift. I want to work a little with FirebaseMessaging, just for the sake of learning the language.

I want to show the fcmToken from FirebaseMessaging in the UI. According to the tutorials I have the following AppDelegate extension to wait for an fcmToken and then to print it.

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    // [START refresh_token]
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")

        let dataDict:[String: String] = ["token": fcmToken]
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)

        // TODO: If necessary send token to application server
        // Note: This callback is fired at each startup and whenever a new token is generated.

    }
    // [END refresh_token]

    // [START ios_10_data_message]
    // Receive data messages on iOS 10+ directly from FCM (bypassing APNSs) when the app is in the foreground.
    // To enable direct data messages, you can set  Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel to true.
    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message:  \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }
    // [END ios_10_data_message]
}
```

In my view controller, in `viewDidLoad` I just want to assign that value of fcmToken to a label as follows.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var labelFcmToken: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        // set FcmToken
        labelFcmToken.text = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

Problem is that `didReceiveRegistrationToken` seems to be some kind of event listener also. So when `viewDidLoad` is called, then the fcmToken is not set yet.

So how, in Swift, can I wait for fcmToken to be available, and then show it in the UI?

(In C#, I would probably bind the label to some property that holds the fcmToken. Then binding itself then takes care of firing an event to update the UI as soon as its value changes)

Answer (score 0):

You have almost done with broadcasting Notification to other classes using `NSNotificationCenter`.

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil, userInfo: dataDict)
```

Have you added observer for that notification `Notification.Name("FCMToken")` in your `viewDidLoad` func?

If not, add it as like below.

```
// MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var labelFcmToken: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    labelFcmToken.text = Messaging.messaging().fcmToken

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.fcmTokenUpdated(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil)
}

deinit {
    //Don't forget to removeObserver 
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: Notification.Name("FCMToken"), object: nil)
}

@objc func fcmTokenUpdated(notification:Notification){

    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: String]{

        labelFcmToken.text = userInfo["token"]
    }
}
```